# Basic linked list implementation in java

Tags: java, data-structures

I am looking for the basic implementation of linked list in Java which has insert() and remove() method.

Thanks.

Comment: Basic implementation of linked list is `LinkedList`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such an implementation exists in the `java.util` package. It is, unsurprisingly, called [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

It has methods such as [`add(int index, E element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add-int-E-), as well as an [`add(E e)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add-E-) to add to the end. There are also multiple `remove(` methods that include removing a given object, the head of the list, or an arbitrary index.

Comment: Yes that is double linked list implementation. I am looking for singly linked list.

Comment: @harshal In what way is a doubly-linked list not appropriate? It simply supersedes a singly-linked list while adding new behavior and not compromising old.